# linux or solaris match files with uniq syntax

Tags: linux, solaris, find, awk, ls

how to match all files that start with the string OS_PATCH 
and ended with .gz

remark -  the solution must to fit  Linux and Solaris OS

this task could be by find command or maybe with ls with Regular Expressions   or any other idea for example awk

for example

```
OS_PATCH-ver.4.577.gz
OS_PATCH-pilot-install.gz
OS_PATCH.upgrade-patch.gz
OS_PATCH_generig-patch.gz
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not tell where you want to look, here are possible ways:

```
find . -name "OS_PATCH*gz"
```

or

```
ls OS_PATCH*gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
find . -regex '.*/OS_PATCH.*\.gz$'
find /folder/where/you/look/for/files -regex '.*/OS_PATCH.*\.gz$'
```

Comment: This wont work with Solaris standard find as `-regex` is a Gnu extension.